# Why doesn't npm upgrade install my 0.0.1 dep with a dependency on '^0.0.0'?

Tags: npm, github-package-registry

So I've read the doc at [npm upgrade#caret dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update#caret-dependencies).  But `npm upgrade` does not seem to work for me.  It is possible this has something to do with `github` packages.  The package that fails to update is a package in our internal github packages repo.

And here is my package.json

```
{ 
  <snip>
 "devDependencies": {
    "@1uphealth/build-lifecycle-scripts": "^0.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.2",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

But asking for an upgrade does nothing.

```
% npm ls --depth=0                                            
@1uphealth/core-example-lib@0.0.0
├── @1uphealth/build-lifecycle-scripts@0.0.0
├── @types/jest@25.2.3
└── jest@26.1.0

% npm upgrade --only=dev
<nothing happens>                                     
% npm upgrade --only=dev @1uphealth/build-lifecycle-scripts
<nothing happens>
```

But, an explicit install of the 0.0.1 version works fine...

```
% npm install '@1uphealth/build-lifecycle-scripts@^0.0.1'
+ @1uphealth/build-lifecycle-scripts@0.0.1
updated 1 package and audited 585 packages in 3.514s
<snip>
% npm ls --depth=0                               
@1uphealth/core-example-lib@0.0.0 /Users/marvin/git/internal/components/0.x/core-example-lib
├── @1uphealth/build-lifecycle-scripts@0.0.1
├── @types/jest@25.2.3
└── jest@26.1.0
```

Here is my `.npmrc`

```
@1uphealth:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/1uphealth
```

So should `npm update` be updating this install?  Does this seem like something broken in `github packages` repository implementation?  Or, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

OK.  So reading more closely, the documentation at [npm-semver](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004) for `caret ranges` explains this.  I had read that page but thought that the basic rules about "major", "minor", "patch" were something that I just understood -- major versions are breaking chnages, minor versions are compatible additions to the API, and patch are fixes/changes that don't affect the API.   But this sentence

> Allows changes that do not modify the left-most non-zero digit in the [major, minor, patch] tuple

explains that it is more subtle.  The basic result is that for `0` major-versions, the **minor** version is considered a breaking change.  So while `^1.0.0` will allow (*be satisfied by*) `1.1.0` and `^2.0.0` will allow `2.1.0`, `^0.0.0` will actually not allow ANYTHING else, and '^0.1.0' will allow only `^0.1.[0-9]*`.

Essentially (mostly) the minor version "becomes" the major version.  So the rationale is that for `0` major versions, many releases will be breaking changes and this allows that to be done without forcing a `1.x` release (which suggests a certain maturity of the component that may not be warranted.)